# jQuery Hover, display and visibility CSS not properly applied in IE7 and below

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, visibility

Can someone please take a look at the small test case below and tell me why the div(.hide) is never visible in IE7 and IE6.

(N.B. I realise that jQuery's hide() & show() methods could be used but I would prefer to use a CSS based solution that relies on classes rather than having jQuery writing inline styles to the DOM.)

```
<html>
<body>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(function() {
                    $("table tr").hover(function() {
                        $(this).addClass("hover");
                    }, function() {
                        $(this).removeClass("hover");
                    });
                });
            });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .hide {
            visibility: hidden;
            display: block;
            width: 16px;
            height: 16px;
            background-color: #f00;
        }
        .hover .hide {
            visibility: visible;
        }
    </style>

    <table style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
            <th class="ident" scope="col">Col1</th>
            <th class="fname" scope="col">Col2</th>
            <th class="lname" scope="col">Col3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td><div class="hide"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td><div class="hide"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td><div class="hide"></div></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td><div class="hide"></div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works for me in IE7-9, Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/HEkqq/  (I didn't change anything)

Comment: why are you trying to support a dying stuff??

Comment: Come now, IE6 may be dying, but 7 is still here.

Comment: I would suggest using firebug lite to find out what's going on http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLJ2RaNZ22E

Comment: I know what's going on in firefox, it's working. IE7&6 are the problem.

Comment: Did my answer below not fix your issue?  Let me know so I can take another swag at it if you're still having trouble.

Comment: That actually does solve the test case. But I did want to apply the class hover to the table rows for other purposes. Why would a class applied to the target element directly work over selecting the element via the .hover class applied to the table row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will fix your issue because I can't actually replicate your problem (I only have IE7 via IE9 available to me), but try doing something like this instead:

```
<html>
<body>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(function() {
                    $("table tr").hover(function() {
                       $(this).find('.redblock').toggleClass('show');
                    });
                });
            });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .redblock{
            visibility: hidden;
            display: block;
            width: 16px;
            height: 16px;
            background-color: #f00;
        }
        .show {
            visibility: visible !important;
        }
    </style>

    <table style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
            <th class="ident" scope="col">Col1</th>
            <th class="fname" scope="col">Col2</th>
            <th class="lname" scope="col">Col3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td><div class="redblock"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td><div class="redblock"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td><div class="redblock"></div></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td><div class="redblock"></div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

The proof is in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HEkqq/7/

Answer (score 1):

You have the CSS wrong:

```
 .hover .hide {
    visibility: visible;
  }
```

should be:

```
 .hover.hide {
    visibility: visible;
  }
```

Also, you aren't toggling the class on the proper element.
See this: http://jsfiddle.net/HEkqq/4/

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(function() {
                $("table tr").hover(function() {
                    $('.hide', this).addClass("hover");
                }, function() {
                    $('.hide', this).removeClass("hover");
                });
            });
        });
```

Also, also, you should to it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/HEkqq/6/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("table tr").hover(function() {
        $('.hide', this).toggleClass("hover");
    });
});
```

Comment: CSS is perfectly correct. I am adding the hover class to the element I want to target, the table row. Also, toggleClass effectivly does the same job.